# JavaScript Freezes The Browser

Tags: javascript, browser, freeze

I'm trying to make a function that generates duplicated css properties for HTML class use. The function works in three steps.

1. Create the object with:

```
    var obj = new module('prefix', 'suffix');
```

2. Add a couple of properties:

```
    obj.addProperty('width', 'px', 2);
    obj.addProperty('height', 'px', 2);
```

3. Run the cloning process with:

```
    obj.clone('15', '3');
```

But than, it freezes for no apparent reason.
Here's the full code:

```
window.cloner_module = function(prefix, suffix) {
    this.properties = []
    this.prefix = prefix;
    this.suffix = suffix;

    this.addProperty = function(option, type, side) {
        var array = [];
        array.push(option, type, side);
        this.properties.push(array);
    }

    this.clone = function(max, step) {

        var array = [];
        var entry_count = 0;
        var innerModuleArray = [];
        var moduleArray = [];
        var property;
        var option;
        var type;
        var side;
        var value;
        var string = "";


        for (var i = 0; i < max; i + step) {
            innerModuleArray = [];
            moduleArray = [];
            moduleArray.push('.' + prefix + i + suffix + '{');

            for (var y = 0; y < this.properties.length; y++) {
                property = this.properties[y];
                option = property[0];
                type = property[1];
                side = property[2];
                value;

                if (!side) {
                    value = i;
                } else if (side == '1') {
                    value = type + i;
                } else if (side == '2') {
                    value = i + type;
                } else {
                    console.log('"Side" property must be between 0 and 2');
                }

                string = option + ": " + value + "; ";
                innerModuleArray.push(string);
            }

            moduleArray.push(innerModuleArray);
            moduleArray.push('}');
            array.push(moduleArray);
            entry_count++;
        }

        this.clones = array;
        this.last_entry_count = entry_count;
        this.last_step_registered = step; 
        this.last_max_registered = max;
    }
}
```

Comment: First thing I noticed is that the parameters in `obj.clone('15', '3')` are being used as numbers. So you will want to use them as such: `obj.clone(15, 3)`. Otherwise it could just be concatenating for each iteration in the loop. Also `i` isn't being update on each loop.

Comment: Maybe you mistyped `i += step` as `i + step`.

Comment: You have infinite loop. :) use `for (var i = 0; i < max; i + =step) {` instead

Answer (score 2):

Your code is entering an infinite loop as a result of your `for` loop, which is in turn causing the browser to freeze. The core problem is the line:

```
for (var i = 0; i < max; i + step)
```

Here the final statement is always equal to 3 (0 + 3), so the loop will never finish. You probably want to change it to:

```
for (var i = 0; i < max; i += step)
```

This edit will continuously increase `i` by `step` each iteration, as was your original intention.

Comment: Then it's probably just a typographical error, vote to close it as such.